# matplotlib.pyplot set_xticks and set_xticklabels issue

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'd like to use set_xticks and set_xticklabels to control the number of labels but the chart doesn't look right.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import seaborn as sns

d = {'sel_date': pd.date_range('2020-01-01', '2021-01-01', 24), 'ID':list('abbb')*6, 'index':np.random.randint(10, size=24)}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
plot = pd.pivot_table(df, values='index', index=['sel_date'],
                    columns=['ID'], aggfunc=np.mean)
plot.fillna(0, inplace=True)
date_fmt = mdates.DateFormatter("%Y-%m")

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 4))
ax = sns.lineplot(data=plot)
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(7))
months = pd.date_range('2020-01', '2021-01', periods=7).strftime('%Y-%m').tolist()
ax.set_xticklabels(months)
plt.show()
```

it returns

```
[Text(0, 0, '2020-01'),
 Text(1, 0, '2020-03'),
 Text(2, 0, '2020-05'),
 Text(3, 0, '2020-07'),
 Text(4, 0, '2020-09'),
 Text(5, 0, '2020-11'),
 Text(6, 0, '2021-01')]
```

[image]

If I plot the x-axis date as datetime, it works

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
date_fmt = mdates.DateFormatter("%Y-%m")
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 4))
ax = sns.lineplot(data=plot)
ax.set(xlabel='')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(date_fmt)
```

[image]

I'd like to know why the first chart doesn't work. thank you

Comment: [Matplotlib represents dates using floating point numbers specifying the number of days since a default epoch of 1970-01-01 UTC;](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/dates_api.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error comes from the fact that matplotlib considers the number of days from 1970-01-01 UTC as abcissa ([see documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/dates_api.html)), as described by [r-beginners](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13107804/r-beginners), and you are selecting the ticks to be from 0 to 6.

The original xticks are (you can check it yourself with a call to `ax.get_xticks()` before setting the custom ticks):

```py
array([18262., 18322., 18383., 18444., 18506., 18567., 18628.])
```

You can either not change the automatic selected ticks (remove `ax.set_xticks(np.arange(7))`) or use the correct values when setting them (not really necessary because the values won't be changed, but I'll leave it here because may be useful to someone in the future):

```py
ax.set_xticks(ax.get_xticks())
months = pd.date_range('2020-01', '2021-01', periods=7).strftime('%Y-%m').tolist()
ax.set_xticklabels(months)
```